# conditionally returning an object type from a function

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

Is there some way to return a *type* from a function in C++? For example, I would like to use something like:

```
// sample pseudo-code: NOT valid C++
template<typename Type1, typename Type2>
type??? getType(bool choice) {
    if(choice == true) {
        return Type1;
    } else {
        return Type2;
    }
}

bool useAwesome = true;

// `Regular` and `Awesome` are classes
getType<Awesome, Regular>(useAwesome) theObject;
```

`if` statement would not work because:

```
if(useAwesome) {
    Awesome theObject;
} else {
    Regular theObject;
}
// theObject goes out of scope!
```

I have read about "first class citizen" and know that the data type is not, but would using `template` help somehow?

Comment: C++ is statically typed. All types have to be known at compile time. If `choice` is determined at runtime only, then this doesn't work.

Comment: It is hard to imagine a common path after the `if`, even assuming that `theObject` remains in scope: if the types are sufficiently different, there is little you can do to the `theObject` object that makes sense to both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do it like that. The type in C++ must be known at compile time, not at run time. You can return `typeid` from a function, but you cannot use that `typeid` to declare variables of the corresponding type.

Answer (score 2):

If you *need* to choose the type at run-time, you'd typically use inheritance:

```
class Base {};

class Awesome : public Base;
class Regular : public Base;

Base *ObjectPointer;

if (useAwesome)
    ObjectPointer = new Aweseome;
else
    ObjectPointer = new Regular;

Base &theObject = *ObjectPointer;
```

When you're done using `theObject`, be sure to `delete ObjectPointer;` (or `delete &theObject;`).

Note that for this to accomplish much, you normally need to define a common interface to use the capabilities of either `Regular` or `Awesome` via their common base class. You'd typically do this by declaring (often pure) virtual functions in the base class, and then implementing those functions in the derived classes. At the very least, you need to declare the destructor virtual in the base class (otherwise, when you try to delete the object via the pointer to the base, you'll get undefined behavior).